# Find the exact value of $x$ if $\frac{\sin x}x =\sqrt x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

It is quite easy to find that x is approximately .802. Is there any way in which we can solve this equation to find the exact value of x?

$\frac{\sin x}{x} = x^{1/2}$

Comment: Why not simplify and ask for $\sin x = x^{3/2}$?  And isn't $x=0$ enough?

Comment: You might want to add some context, like how you came up with this question, and also what do you mean by "exact value"?

Comment: "quite easy" I presume not by hand?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I presume by something like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wwndvyfc38). (Which I was about to post anyway)

Comment: It seems like it's not solvable algebraically, so there is no exact answer. Unless someone manages to turn the sine into an exponential, and with subsequent series of steps isolate the x using the Lambert W function. If it's possible then more likely than not it is hard, tedious, and requires some complex analysis. I don't exactly know if I'm right, but with my naked eye, this is not solvable

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't think $x=0$ is a solution, since to transform $\sin x=x^{3/2}$ into $\sin x/x=x^{1/2}$ one needs to assume $x\neq 0$. The equation presented in the answer has $1$ at the LHS and $0$ in the RHS for $x=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact value, no way but good approximations (remember that $x=\cos(x)$ does not show explicit solutions).

Plotting the function, we can see that the root is close to $\frac \pi 4$. So, to make expressions "simple", let us use $[1,n]$ Padé approximants for $\frac{\sin x}{x} - x^{1/2}$. They will write
$$\frac{\sin x}{x} - x^{1/2}=\frac {\frac{4 \sqrt{2}-\pi ^{3/2}}{2 \pi }+a_1^{(n)} \left(x-\frac \pi 4 \right)}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \left(x-\frac \pi 4 \right)^k }$$ from which the approximate solution
$$x_{(n)}=\frac \pi 4 +\frac{\pi ^{3/2}-4 \sqrt{2}}{2 \pi  a_1^{(n)}}$$ This would give quite nasty formulae since
$$a_1^{(0)}=\frac{-8 \sqrt{2}+2 \sqrt{2} \pi -\pi ^{3/2}}{\pi ^2}$$
$$a_1^{(1)}=\frac{64-24 \pi +16 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2}-3 \pi ^2+\sqrt{2} \pi ^{5/2}-60 \sqrt{2 \pi
   }}{2 \pi  \left(8 \sqrt{2}-2 \sqrt{2} \pi +\pi ^{3/2}\right)}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_{(n)} \approx \\
 0 & 0.8027883593 \\
 1 & 0.8028042932 \\
 2 & 0.8028037219 \\
 3 & 0.8028037319 \\
 4 & 0.8028037317 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

If you use Newton method, it would be much less tedious and you could get as many decimal places as you wish
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.785398163397448309615660845819875721049292350 \\
 1 & 0.802788359292669370099497626707352560682643311 \\
 2 & 0.802803731726750434568551610417466777052560631 \\
 3 & 0.802803731737889315511829476566222402429256954 \\
 4 & 0.802803731737889315511835324604000441222668911
\end{array}
\right)$$